# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i try to fetch data from mongodb database using nodejs and mongorito orm for mongodb database, but its show me following error

```
kaushik@root:~/NodeJS/application$ node run.js 
/home/kaushik/NodeJS/run.js:16
        var posts = yield Users.all();
                          ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
kaushik@root:~/NodeJS/application$
```

here is **run.js**

```
var Mongorito = require('mongorito')
var Model = Mongorito.Model

var Users = Model.extend({
    collection: 'testing'// collection name
});
var posts = yield Users.all();
console.log(posts)
```

i also try 'use strict' but its give following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
```

Comment: You have an extra comma `collection: 'testing',` <---- get rid of that comma

Comment: ohk, now i removed extra comma but its still given error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongorito doesn't use generators ([anymore](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/mongorito/commit/fc66a113872d26b7348c8b032086f607e31bab72)), which means you can't use `yield` (even so, the error you're getting is because `yield` is only valid *inside* generator functions, but you're using it at the top level of your code). It uses promises now.

If you're willing to use Node v7 (or a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)), you can use `async/await`. Your code would look something like this:

```
const Mongorito = require('mongorito');
const Model     = Mongorito.Model;
const Users     = Model.extend({ collection: 'test' });

void async function() {
  await Mongorito.connect('localhost/test');
  let posts = await Users.all();
  console.log(posts)
  await Mongorito.disconnect();
}();
```

Because `await` only works inside `async` functions, the above code uses an async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to wrap the code in.

For older versions of Node, you can also use a regular promise chain:

```
Mongorito.connect('localhost/test').then(() => {
  return Users.all();
}).then(posts => {
  console.log(posts);
}).then(() => {
  return Mongorito.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: superb.. Thank you robertklep :) its work and error is gone. but console.log(postes) gives result like this child {
  attributes: 
   { _id: 58d38170b380ac18428cac9c,
     created: '2017-03-23 13:34:00.592065',
     username: 'me',
     title: 'kd'
    },
  changed: {},
  previous: {},
  options: { populate: {} } }

Comment: can we fetch result more accurate ?

Comment: @KaushikMakwana try `console.log(posts.map(p => p.toJSON()))`